# Twilio video with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, twilio, twilio-video

We are planning to integrate `Twilio video SDKs` for video conferencing in our existing application which is in `Flutter`. From the documentation of Twilio SDKs it is pretty sure that it is just for native Android development and not for frameworks like Flutter. So how can I to use Twilio video SDKs in my mobile app development (Android and iOS)?

Is it possible to create UI in both native Android and the framework (Flutter) at the same time within same application?

Is it technically possible and if yes, how to do it?

Comment: You can use [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to call native APIs.

Comment: I wanted a UI through native code(android_manifest.xml) for this particular feature of video conferencing. How can I achieve this while using the Flutter for other features of the application?

Answer (score 0):

There is a existing Twilio Video Flutter plugin already hosted on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video). The repository can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video).